# Пространство до строки в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

У меня программа, которая должна делать все слова с большой буквы. Я написал версию, которая делает слова с заглавной после первого слова. Надо сделать так, чтобы еще первое слово было с большой :

```
var word = prompt('Какие слова вам сделать с большой буквы? ');
var wordEnd = '';
for(i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    wordEnd += (word[i - 1] == " " || word[i -1] == "") ? word[i].toUpperCase() : word[i];
}
alert(wordEnd);
```

Надо поставит условие, есть ли что-то вообще до буквы, вот я и думаю как обозначается пустота до строки.

Если предложите другие решения этой задачи, буду очень рад!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При проверке нулевого символа строки, предыдущий индекс будет `-1`, а так как такого поля в строке нет, результат будет `undefined`.

Следовательно, нужно добавить проверку на равенство `undefined`: `word[i-1] == undefined`

Пример:

```js
var word = prompt('Какие слова вам сделать с большой буквы? ');
var wordEnd = '';
for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  wordEnd += (word[i - 1] == " " || word[i - 1] == "" || word[i - 1] == undefined) ? word[i].toUpperCase() : word[i];
}
console.log(wordEnd);
```

---

Кроме того можно воспользоваться простой регуляркой:

```js
var word = prompt('Какие слова вам сделать с большой буквы? ');
var wordEnd = word.replace(/\b./g, $0 => $0.toUpperCase());
console.log(wordEnd);
```

Comment: А вы знаете, что `\b` не работает с кириллицей?